# Why grep '[^a-z]+$' matches digits?

Tags: regex, grep

Could you explain why the regular expression "grep -E '[^a-z]+$' testfile" also matches lines that consist only of digits?

For example for the testfile:

```
Hi
this 
is test file
123 456
asdf
ASDF
```

this expression will match:

```
123 456
ASDF
```

At the same time "grep ^[a-z]+$" as expected matches lines:

```
this
asdf
```

Comment: You still have a space at the beginning of each line (as @CodeGnome pointed out), and I don't think they belong there.  To activate code formatting you only need four spaces at the beginning of the line.  You have five leading spaces, so the fifth space is being treated as a literal space character.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was actually a typo made by OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^a-z]` means "any character that is NOT in the range `a-z`". The `^` at the beginning of a character class `[]` inverts the character class.

Perhaps you meant `^[a-z]+$` ?

Comment: Oh! Yes, thanks! I updated the post about ^[a-z] before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is incorrect. It will only match `123 456`. Using `^` inside a character class `[]` is for negation.

For anchoring you need to use `^` outside of character class.

Answer (score 1):

### Problems

1. As posted, your corpus has leading spaces.
2. Your character class is wrong; you haven't anchored the class with a carat, you've negated the class.

### Solution

Use POSIX character classes to handle leading spaces, as well as matching only digits and spaces in the rest of the line.

```
$ grep -E '^[[:space:][:digit:]]+$' /tmp/corpus 
 123 456
```